# Can't wrap outer tags in dom-repeat. Polymer seems to automatically close them

Tags: html, css, for-loop, whitespace, polymer-1.0

Per the template below, I am trying to keep words from breaking using CSS white-space tags. The problem is Polymer seems to automatically close the open tags I am using as the wrapper. Any help?

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{getHiddenStrArr(diffObj.value)}}" as="char" >

      <template is="dom-if" if="{{!index}}">
        <together>[
      </template>

            <template is="dom-if" if="{{!isASpace(char)}}">
              <span class="added-char">{{char}}</span>
            </template>

            <template is="dom-if" if="{{isASpace(char)}}">

              ]</together>

              <span class="added-char">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>

              <together>[

            </template>

      <template is="dom-if" if="{{isEndOfList(diffObj.value, index)}}">
        ]</together>
      </template>


    </template>
```

Resulting HTML:

[image]

I know the logic is correct as I used "[" and "]"to represent what the tags are doing visually. Such as:

```
[ - - - - ]    [ - - - ]    [ - - ! ]
```

Comment: I don't see a dom-repeat in your code. My suggestion would be to use something like <together>{{computedProperty()}}</together>. Check this to learn more about computed property. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#computed-properties

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sirk but computing a value is not possible in this case based on how the string gets computed (I'm using diff logic etc.) The main problem per the title is that dom-repeat seems to be closing my wrapper tags prematurely. Any idea why?

Comment: I don't think you can construct partial dom in a template. It is used to encapsulate a complete dom. You should look at Polymer's dom-api to  manipulate your dom in the script.

Comment: Do you know of a way to return non escaped html? I may be able to do it that way instead.